# Laravel - Eloquent ORM - existing database

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to learn about laravel / eloquent orm.

How does one implement an existing database/table with eloquent.  Any examples out there?  Everything out there shows how to create database/tables. I'd like to use existing data structure and implement classes.

Comment: try reading the docs, creating tables is only handled by migrations. Eloquent can work with any pre existing schema

Comment: Thanks....I dont see anywhere in the docs that refer to an existing schema.

Comment: ... it's pretty much top of the eloquent page! See my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try reading the docs, creating tables is only handled by migrations. Eloquent can work with any pre existing schema

Pretty much top of the Laravel Eloquent page http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#basic-usage

```
class User extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'my_users';

}
```